# CSS group style definitions

Tags: css

I am learning CSS so this may be a very basic/silly question but I cannot find it anywhere, sorry. I have the following CSS code:

```css
#table-of-contents ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#table-of-contents ol > li {
  display: table;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

#table-of-contents ol > li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 0.6em;    
}
#table-of-contents li ol > li {
  margin: 0;
}

#table-of-contents li ol > li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}
```

and I am wondering if there is any way of somehow writing only once the `#table-of-contents`, something like

```css
#table-of-contents {
    ol {
      list-style-type: none;
      counter-reset: item;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    ol > li {
      display: table;
      counter-increment: item;
      margin-bottom: 0.6em;
    }

    ol > li:before {
      content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
      display: table-cell;
      padding-right: 0.6em;    
    }
    li ol > li {
      margin: 0;
    }

    li ol > li:before {
      content: counters(item, ".") " ";
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_(stylesheet_language)

Answer (score 2):

It is called [*CSS Nesting*](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-nesting-1/) and is in the works, not official yet. But it's available in CSS preprocessing language such as Sass, Less, Stylus. You can consider using those.